# M2: Impossible install language pack

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I'm trying install Czech language pack  via composer from mageplaza:
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-czech-language-pack.html

When I run then get issue:

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for mageplaza/magento-2-czech-language-pack dev-maste                                 r -> satisfiable by mageplaza/magento-2-czech-language-pack[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install mageplaza/module-core 1.4.1
    - Can only install one of: mageplaza/module-core[1.3.13, 1.3.12].
    - Can only install one of: mageplaza/module-core[1.3.13, 1.3.12].
    - Can only install one of: mageplaza/module-core[1.3.13, 1.3.12].
    - mageplaza/magento-2-czech-language-pack dev-master requires mageplaza/modu                                 le-core ^1.3.13|dev-master -> satisfiable by mageplaza/module-core[1.3.13, 1.4.0                                 , 1.4.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install mageplaza/module-core 1.4.0
    - Installation request for mageplaza/module-core (locked at 1.3.12, required                                  as ^1.3) -> satisfiable by mageplaza/module-core[1.3.12].
```

I understand I need to upgrade module-core.

Can anyone confirm I update module-core in this way? (now website is on live and I would not want to have any complications).

```
$ composer require mageplaza/module-core:1.4.1 --no-update
$ composer update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to be sure just edit the composer.json from 1.3.12 to 1.4.1 and then use the update command to update it

> composer update mageplaza/module-core

This will only update the core module. The composer update without an argument will try to update everything thats possible according to your composer.json but I won't recommend that.